# How to get the exe path in nsis script?

Tags: path, exe, nsis

I am writing an uninstaller for my application, and I need to check from which directory uninstaller is invoked (because I want to restrict uninstallation from any other directory).

I am using built-in variable `$EXEPATH` but it is giving me `C:\Users\MyUser\Local\Temp\~nsu.tmp` instead of current directory.

I also used windows API `GetModuleFileName` using nsis, but it is also giving same output. How to get the current directory for the executable?

Comment: Are you looking for $EXEDIR?

Comment: @kichik `$EXEDIR` also gives the same output.

Comment: It's not supposed to. Either there is a bug in your NSIS version or you're executing the uninstaller in a nonstandard way.

Comment: @kichik I am using nsis version 2.46 and I tried for installer, it is working fine. I guess `$EXEPATH` is giving correct output because nsis internally creating temporary exe and `$EXEPATH` is giving that path.
My problem is resolved using `$INSTDIR`, it contains current directory path if it is not reset using `InstallDirRegKey`.

Comment: Doh. Yes, that's the one I was thinking of. You don't even need to read it from registry. It should contain the path before the copy.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary directory in the form of `C:\Users\MyUser\Local\Temp\~nsu.tmp` is probably the directory where the uninstaller is actually running.

To avoid problems with impossibility to remove the uninstaller executable because it is locked while running (so it need a reboot to be actually deleted), it is common to copy the uninstaller .exe to a temporary place and run it from there.

If you do not want the unistaller to fork itself into a temp directory, you can invoke it this way:

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'
```

The trick involves the `_?` special parameter described in the [manual](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2.2).

Comment: I guess this will work if we are calling uninstaller from nsis script. But in my case, user can directly double click it to start uninstallation.

Comment: Let me make my requirement more clear. Suppose my software installed directory is **C:\Program Files\MySoftware**. All my binaries, dlls and uninstaller.exe will be in this directory. So I want uninstaller to be launched only from this directory.If someone copies uninstaller.exe to some other directory, uninstallation should not work and to get the executable directory I am using `$EXEPATH` but it is giving tmp directory as path.Using `_?` we can explicitely set this tmp directory, but my requirement is not that.

Answer (score 0):

`$InstDir` in the uninstaller is set to the path where the uninstaller logically exists. Use $InstDir in place of $ExeDir in the uninstaller.

The uninstaller copies itself to %temp% so code like `DeleteFile $InstDir\Uninst.exe` will work even though Windows does not allow you to delete running .exe files.